# What type definitions does the Angular official reference documentation use?

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc, code-documentation

In the official documentation, you often see types denoted like this:

`!Array.<string>=` (e.g. here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

What does this mean? (especially the ! and = signs in my example)? Where is it explained? Is this a common standard somehow I was missing until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concerning AngularJS Documentation

To cite the Angular [guide on writing AngularJS Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation)

> The AngularJS project uses a form of **jsdoc** for all of its documentation.
>   (...)
>   The flavour of jsdoc used by AngularJS is called **ngdoc** and is parsed by a Node.js utility called [Dgeni](https://github.com/angular/dgeni).

### Where are the type annotations explained?

here: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html

So, e.g. the `!` here means, that the parameter cannot be `null`.
The `=` means, that this parameter is optional.